# How to get value off JSON in Robot framework

Tags: python, logging, automated-tests, robotframework

I have  for example a log that will change each time it is run an example is below. I will like to take one of the value(id) lets say as a variable and log only the id to console or use that value somewhere else.

```
[
  {
    "@type": "type",
    "href": [
      {
        "@url": "url1",
        "@method": "get"
      },
      {
        "@url": "url2",
        "@method": "post"
      },
            
      {
        "@url": "url3",
        "@method": "post"
      }
    ],
    "id": "3",
    "meta": [
      {
        "key": "key1",
        "value": "value1"
      },
      {
        "key": "key2",
        "value": "value2"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to get the id in a variable because the id changes after each time the robot framework is ran

Comment: You should provide a code sample, what have you tried and how it should be improved. Right now the only thing you can see from the sample is that your JSON element is actually a list with a dictionary nested inside - Maybe you should try to extract the list element first and try to work with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can see here that the JSON you are getting is in list format. Which means that to get a value from the JSON, you'll first need to read the JSON object in, then get the dictionary out of the list and only then access the key value you'd need to extract.

Robot Framework supports using Python statements with `Evaluate` keyword. When we need to simply parse some string to JSON we can get by using

```py
${DATA}=    Evaluate    json.loads("""${DATA}""")
```

Notice that the `${DATA}` here should contain your JSON as a string.

Now that we have the JSON object, we can do whatever we want with it. We can actually see from your JSON that it is actually a dictionary nested inside a list object (See surrounding `[]`). So first, extract dictionary from the list, then access the dictionary key normally. The following should work fine.

```py
${DICT}=    Get From List          ${DATA}    0
${ID}=      Get From Dictionary    ${DICT}    id
```